# Page redirect to previous page after authentication

Tags: php

I was trying to redirect users to the previous page after authentication. It works well with the below codes.

The file `login_page.php` (the page where users enter login credentials) contains the below code which stores the **SOURCE URL** and passes it to next page.

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" value=<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ; ?> />
```

File `do_authentication.php` (page which does the authentication) has the code `echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content=0;url='$_POST[url]'>";` which redirects to **SOURCE URL**

In the normal situation it works, but in situations when user enters wrong credentials, the page is redirected to `login_page.php` and it asks the user to try again with correct credentials. At that time, 'url' value changes to `login_page.php`.

What is the correct/better logic to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always used the session to retain the original page when doing login. This will not work if the session isn't supported. Then I just send the user to the home page.

A Stack Overflow post discussing this is *[Redirect to previous page after logging in using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308003)*.

Comment: Session works for me....


Login_page.php

`//Create session to redirect page to original pg
if(!isset($_SESSION['url']))
{
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}`


do_authentication.php

`echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content=0;url='$_SESSION[url]'>";
unset($_SESSION['url']);`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
header("location: ".$_POST['url']); // Redirects to posted page
exit; // Prevents execution of other code after this
```

Comment: this and the referer both work first time around, but not after a failed login.  At that point the referer and url are the login itself.

Answer (score 0):

In `login_page.php`, you could check if you already passed a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator); if so, pass this one instead of the HTTP_REFERER.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['url']) ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value=<?php echo $_POST['url'] ; ?> />
<?php else ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value=<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ; ?> />
```

Or in a more concise way

```
<?php $url= (isset($_POST['url'])) ? $_POST['url'] : $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="url" value=<?php echo $url; ?> />
```

Comment: This also gives the same result. After failed login, url value changes to login_page.php

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using session variables to store the value of the page you want to redirect to. HTTP_REFERRER is not right option.

Answer (score 0):

Just try below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" value=<?php echo pathinfo(__FILE__,PATHINFO_FILENAME ).".".pathinfo(__FILE__,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); ?> />
```