# How load an internal logging page if user not logged in Using Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement a logging-redirect page without losing the current page's data. I found [this answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2308011/1735543) interesting, particularly his 3rd option, but I am not understanding how to achieve this. I am using PHP in backend.

Since because my pages been loaded according to the hash value change i believe an ajax via is an only solution

Thanks n advance

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this  by storing data either into a session variable array or temp database table. I would prefer to store it in session.

**If you are doing it using session then it can be:**

When user clicks on submit, do you check that the user is logged in or not? If yes, then store data into a table. If not, then store it into a session array, say `xyz[]`. After storing it, redirect the user to a login page. After login, you can check if the session array `xyz[]` contains any value. If it does, store it into a particular table and don't forget to **unset** session array `xyz[]`. Otherwise, redirect user to **home**.

**If you are doing it using the DB then it can be:**

When user clicks on submit, do you check that the user is logged in or not? If yes, then store data into db table. If not, then store it into a **temporary db table**. After storing it, redirect user to login page. After login, you can check if the **temp db table** contains any record. If it does, then move it into a particular table and don't forget to **delete** record from the temp db table. Otherwise, redirect user to **home**.

**or else best way**

In starting of your form just check if user logged in or not? if **not** then redirect him to login page. Otherwise, allow them to fill data in form.

Comment: thanks for the idea.. in my case my pages are loaded according to the hash changes so the redirecting back to the hash location is very deficult.. do you have any idea to achieve this via ajax calling?

Comment: save the hash value to the session as well, then retrieve it after login to redirect

Comment: no hash value cannot be retrieved by php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905